# Wildfly Logs are not saved

Tags: java, logging, jboss, wildfly, logfile

After restarting my Ubuntu VM, Wildfly 18 automatically starts.
From ps aux

> wildfly   1031  0.0  0.0  20048  3508 ?        Ss   Dez18   0:00 /bin/bash /opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh standalone standalone.xml 0.0.0.0
>   wildfly   1067  0.0  0.0   4628  1756 ?        S    Dez18   0:00 /bin/sh /opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml -b 0.0.0.0
>   wildfly   1482 35.2  7.0 1658040 572176 ?      Sl   Dez18   0:36 /opt/jdk-13.0.1/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs

But my server.log is empty (cat /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log gives me no messages about startup process of wildfly etc.).

When I make a "service wildfly restart" no additional Entries are inserted into server.log. How can I get access to my Log?
I think I`ve changed nothing in comparison to the standard config.

**/standalone/configuration/logging.properties**

```
loggers=sun.rmi,io.jaegertracing.Configuration,org.jboss.as.config,com.arjuna

logger.level=INFO
logger.handlers=FILE,CONSOLE

logger.sun.rmi.level=WARN
logger.sun.rmi.useParentHandlers=true

logger.io.jaegertracing.Configuration.level=WARN
logger.io.jaegertracing.Configuration.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.jboss.as.config.level=DEBUG
logger.org.jboss.as.config.useParentHandlers=true

logger.com.arjuna.level=WARN
logger.com.arjuna.useParentHandlers=true

handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.level=INFO
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=COLOR-PATTERN
handler.CONSOLE.properties=enabled,autoFlush,target
handler.CONSOLE.enabled=true
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.target=SYSTEM_OUT

handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=ALL
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.FILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.enabled=true
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.fileName=/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log

formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n

formatter.COLOR-PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n
```

**Output from standalone-cli**
    [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=logging:read-resource(recursive=true)
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {
            "add-logging-api-dependencies" => true,
            "use-deployment-logging-config" => true,
            "async-handler" => undefined,
            "console-handler" => {"CONSOLE" => {
                "autoflush" => true,
                "enabled" => true,
                "encoding" => undefined,
                "filter" => undefined,
                "filter-spec" => undefined,
                "formatter" => "%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n",
                "level" => "INFO",
                "name" => "CONSOLE",
                "named-formatter" => "COLOR-PATTERN",
                "target" => "System.out"
            }},
            "custom-formatter" => undefined,
            "custom-handler" => undefined,
            "file-handler" => undefined,
            "filter" => undefined,
            "json-formatter" => undefined,
            "log-file" => undefined,
            "logger" => {
                "com.arjuna" => {
                    "category" => "com.arjuna",
                    "filter" => undefined,
                    "filter-spec" => undefined,
                    "handlers" => undefined,
                    "level" => "WARN",
                    "use-parent-handlers" => true
                },
                "io.jaegertracing.Configuration" => {
                    "category" => "io.jaegertracing.Configuration",
                    "filter" => undefined,
                    "filter-spec" => undefined,
                    "handlers" => undefined,
                    "level" => "WARN",
                    "use-parent-handlers" => true
                },
                "org.jboss.as.config" => {
                    "category" => "org.jboss.as.config",
                    "filter" => undefined,
                    "filter-spec" => undefined,
                    "handlers" => undefined,
                    "level" => "DEBUG",
                    "use-parent-handlers" => true
                },
                "sun.rmi" => {
                    "category" => "sun.rmi",
                    "filter" => undefined,
                    "filter-spec" => undefined,
                    "handlers" => undefined,
                    "level" => "WARN",
                    "use-parent-handlers" => true
                }
            },
            "logging-profile" => undefined,
            "pattern-formatter" => {
                "PATTERN" => {
                    "color-map" => undefined,
                    "pattern" => "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"
                },
                "COLOR-PATTERN" => {
                    "color-map" => undefined,
                    "pattern" => "%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"
                }
            },
            "periodic-rotating-file-handler" => {"FILE" => {
                "append" => true,
                "autoflush" => true,
                "enabled" => true,
                "encoding" => undefined,
                "file" => {
                    "relative-to" => "jboss.server.log.dir",
                    "path" => "server.log"
                },
                "filter" => undefined,
                "filter-spec" => undefined,
                "formatter" => "%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n",
                "level" => "ALL",
                "name" => "FILE",
                "named-formatter" => "PATTERN",
                "suffix" => ".yyyy-MM-dd"
            }},
            "periodic-size-rotating-file-handler" => undefined,
            "root-logger" => {"ROOT" => {
                "filter" => undefined,
                "filter-spec" => undefined,
                "handlers" => [
                    "CONSOLE",
                    "FILE"
                ],
                "level" => "INFO"
            }},
            "size-rotating-file-handler" => undefined,
            "socket-handler" => undefined,
            "syslog-handler" => undefined,
            "xml-formatter" => undefined
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that server.log has owner root because of prior testings ... just deleted it and now its re-created with owner wildfly.